# AngularFire2 unsubscribe is not a function

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

I am trying to write a signout method.Before signing out im trying to unsubscribe my previous subscribtions otherwise i get many subscribe and permission  errors

this is signout method(button click triggers this)

```
console.log(this.profileData);
this.profileData.unsubscribe();

  this.app.auth().signOut().then(function() {

    alert("you successfully signed out");

  }, function(error) {
  alert("error");
  });
```

this is how i subscribe

```
    this.profileData = this.fire.authState.switchMap(auth => this.db.object(`profile/${auth.uid}`).valueChanges());
  this.profileData.subscribe(profile =>{...
```

[image]

Comment: this question is still active

Answer (score 1):

`unsubscribe` is interface for subscription, which returned by `this.profileData.subscribe(...)`. It seems currently `this.profileData` is assigned to Observable instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to unsubscribe an observable, not a subscription.
You should do this instead:

```
this.profileData = this.fire.authState.switchMap(auth => this.db.object(`profile/${auth.uid}`).valueChanges());
this.profileSubcription = this.profileData.subscribe(profile =>{...});

console.log(this.profileData);
this.profileSubcription.unsubscribe();

this.app.auth().signOut().then(function() {

 alert("you successfully signed out");

}, function(error) {
 alert("error");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with typescript syntax. I needed to unsubsribe in another method then I subscribed previously.
What finally worked for me was this:

```
class SomeClassName {
unsubscribePosts: any;

startListening() {
  if (this.unsubscribePosts) {
    this.unsubscribePosts()
  }
let u = onSnapshot(query,...)
this.unsubscribePosts = u
}
}
```